# How to Automatically Insert SUM Formula on Value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I always work on my `.xls` that exported from my office application, but there is just value on account column that is a sum of total details in that account.

Can macro VBA automatically fill the values (in yellow highlighted cells) with `sum formula`?

[My Sheet.xls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2lO4.png)

[image]